# How can I repair this?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  cccc codeblocks-contrib-common codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 cppcheck cscope
  libwxsmithlib0 python-pygments valgrind

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:

  libwxgtk2.8-dev | libwxgtk3.0-dev wx-common codeblocks-contrib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  codeblocks

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 624 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,868 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,233 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 codeblocks amd64 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1
  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu/pool/main/c/codeblocks/codeblocks_16.01~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Try to get a valid ppa for codeblocks-stable, it seems like it doesn't exist.

Comment: The PPA *does* work though and even the download URL reported in the output for returning a 404 seems functional to me, as I can paste it in a browser and download that file. Maybe it was just a temporary problem on Launchpad and you should just try again. What's really bad though is the `624 not upgraded` - you should really update your installed packages! Run `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade`.